# pivot long form categorical data by group and dummy code categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

For the following dataframe, I am trying to pivot the categorical variable ('purchase_item') into wide format and dummy code them as 1/0 - based on whether or not a customer purchased it in each of the 4 quarters within 2016.

[image]

I would like to generate a pivotted dataframe as follows:
[image]

To get the desired result shown above, I have tried basically in various ways to combine groupby/pivot_table functions with a call to get_dummies() function in pandas.  Example:
`data.groupby(["cust_id", "purchase_qtr"])["purchase_item"].reset_index().get_dummies()`

However, none of my attempts have worked thus far.

Can somebody please help me generate the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to get the crosstabulation, and then force all values > 1 to become 1, while keeping all 0's as they are:

##### TL;DR

```py
out = (
    pd.crosstab([df["cust_id"], df["purchase_qtr"]], df["purchase_item"])
    .gt(0)
    .astype(int)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Breaking it all down:

##### Create Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "group1": np.repeat(["a", "b", "c"], 4),
    "group2": [1, 2, 3] * 4,
    "item": np.random.choice(["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "zx"], size=12)
})

print(df)
   group1  group2 item
0       a       1   cd
1       a       2   ef
2       a       3   gh
3       a       1   ef
4       b       2   zx
5       b       3   ab
6       b       1   ab
7       b       2   gh
8       c       3   gh
9       c       1   cd
10      c       2   ef
11      c       3   gh
```

##### Cross Tabulation

This returns a frequency table indicating how often each of the categories are observed together:

```py
crosstab = pd.crosstab([df["group1"], df["group2"]], df["item"])

print(crosstab)
item           ab  cd  ef  gh  zx
group1 group2
a      1        0   1   1   0   0
       2        0   0   1   0   0
       3        0   0   0   1   0
b      1        1   0   0   0   0
       2        0   0   0   1   1
       3        1   0   0   0   0
c      1        0   1   0   0   0
       2        0   0   1   0   0
       3        0   0   0   2   0
```

##### Coerce Counts to Dummy Codes

Since we want to dummy code, and not count the co-occurance of categories, we can use a quick trick to force all values greater than 0 `gt(0)` to become 1 `astype(int)`

```py
item           ab  cd  ef  gh  zx
group1 group2
a      1        0   1   1   0   0
       2        0   0   1   0   0
       3        0   0   0   1   0
b      1        1   0   0   0   0
       2        0   0   0   1   1
       3        1   0   0   0   0
c      1        0   1   0   0   0
       2        0   0   1   0   0
       3        0   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: Although this works for the example here, for a very large dataset, it seems to result in fewer number of cust_ids than would be expected from the long format dataframe. Any idea how to prevent this? I get the same issue from the other alternatives listed below also

Answer (score 1):

You can do in one line via several tricks.

### 1) Unique Index count in junction with casting as bool

Works in any case even when you do not have any other column besides `index`, `columns` and `values`. This code implies to count unique indices of each index-column intersection and returning `1` incase its more than `0` else `0`.

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(index=['cust_id','purchase_qtr'], 
                             columns='purchase_item',
                             values='index',
                             aggfunc='nunique', fill_value=0)\
                .astype(bool).astype(int)
```

### 2) Checking if any other column is not null

If you have other columns besides `index`, `columns` and `values` AND want to use them for intuition. Like `purchase_date` in your case. It is more intutive because you can "read" it like: *Check per customer per quarter if the purchase date of the item is not null and parse them as integer.*

```
df.pivot_table(index=['cust_id','purchase_qtr'],
               columns='purchase_item',values='purchase_date',
               aggfunc=lambda x: all(pd.notna(x)), fill_value=0)\
  .astype(int)
```

### 3) Seeing `len` of elements falling in each index-column intersection

This sees`len` of elements falling in each each index-column intersection and returning `1` incase its more than `0` else `0`. Same intuitive approach:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['cust_id','purchase_qtr'], 
               columns='purchase_item',
               values='purchase_date',
               aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)\
  .astype(bool).astype(int)
```

All return desired dataframe:

[image]

Note that you should be only using `crosstab` when you don't have a dataframe already as it calls `pivot_table` internally.

Comment: Although this works for the example here, for a very large dataset, it seems to result in fewer number of cust_ids than would be expected from the long format dataframe. Any idea how to prevent this? I get the same issue from the other alternatives listed above also.